# Redhat Ansible Tower and Gitlab deployment

Tags: nginx, gitlab, ansible-tower

I am trying to deploy RH Ansible tower and GitLab on the RHEL8.3 server. I am able to deploy GitLab successfully and access it through the browser. But when I am trying to deploy Ansible Tower on the same machine, it is throwing below error. Since both the services are using the same port 80, Ansible Tower installation is failing. How to run both the Gitlab and Ansible Tower on the same machine. I am trying to run Gitlab at **https://xx.xx.xx.xx:9443/** and Ansible tower at https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/** . Could you please help me?

````
Aug 13 11:23:46 tower_centos nginx[893591]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us>
Aug 13 11:23:47 tower_centos nginx[893591]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us>
Aug 13 11:23:47 tower_centos nginx[893591]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us>
Aug 13 11:23:48 tower_centos nginx[893591]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us>
Aug 13 11:23:48 tower_centos nginx[893591]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us>
Aug 13 11:23:49 tower_centos nginx[893591]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

After long googling and research, found the below answer and it worked. You need to send the port in the ansible tower deployment
First I deployed Gitlab and then ansible tower. and then run the made

> SELinux as permissive

and ran below command

> ./setup.sh -e nginx_https_port=8443 -e nginx_http_port=85